# How to change listview header's forecolor? C# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listview

I know I can change the `OwnerDraw` property to `true` and then handle the `DrawColumnHeader` event but if I do it like this, I have to take care of everything in drawing the header.

Is there anyway that I just change the foreground color and everything else is drawn with defaults?

Comment: No, those headers are drawn according to the visual styles theme selected by the user.  A gradient fill on later Windows versions, it isn't just one color.  Do ask yourself if overriding the user's preference is *really* something you ought to do.  And yes, use OwnerDraw to force your preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

Create a new WinForm project, drag a **ListView** control onto the form, set **OwnerDraw = true**, **View = Details** in the Properties pane, then handle the **DrawColumnHeader** event.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.SetLastColumnWidth();

            this.theListView.Layout += delegate
            {
                this.SetLastColumnWidth();
            };
        }

        private void SetLastColumnWidth()
        {
            // Force the last ListView column width to occupy all the
            // available space.
            this.theListView.Columns[ this.theListView.Columns.Count - 1 ].Width = -2;
        }

        private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader( object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e )
        {
            // Fill header background with solid yello color.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle( Brushes.Yellow, e.Bounds );
            // Let ListView draw everything else.
            e.DrawText();
        }
    }
}
```