# Change listview header' color?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How do I change the `ListView` Header Color?
If you know how to do it, please give a code example.

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.ListView lvFiles;
```

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818224/how-to-change-listview-headers-forecolor-c-sharp-windows-form-application

Answer (score 6):

that's not a good question trying to ask us to do it, but here is a code sample.

```
ListView lvFiles= new ListView();
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   lvFiles.View = View.Details;
   lvFiles.OwnerDraw = true;
   lvFiles.Size = new Size(200, 100);

   lvFiles.DrawColumnHeader += new DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventHandler(lv_DrawColumn Header);
   lvFiles.DrawSubItem += new DrawListViewSubItemEventHandler(lv_DrawSubItem);

   lv.Columns.Add("Col1");
   lv.Columns.Add("Col1");
   lv.Columns.Add("Col1");

   this.Controls.Add(lv);

   lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "One", "Two","Three" }));
   lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "One", "Two","Three" }));
   lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "One", "Two","Three" }));
}

void lv_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgse)
{
   if ((e.ItemState & ListViewItemStates.Focused) 0)
   {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight,e.Bounds);
      e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, lv.Font,SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.Bounds);
   }
   else
   {
      e.DrawBackground();
      e.DrawText();
   }
}

void lv_DrawColumnHeader(object sender,DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.GreenYellow, e.Bounds);
   e.DrawText();
}
```